# pass reference of primitive data types to functions in ruby

Tags: ruby

By default ruby passes copy of primitive values and references for object types. How to pass references of `primitive` type variables (ex: integers, floating points) into a function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ruby doesn't pass arguments by reference:

```
def change(x)
  x = 2  # this assigns to a local variable 'x'
end

a = 1
change(a)
a #=> 1
```

You could pass a mutable object instead, e.g. a hash "containing" an integer:

```
def change(h)
  h[:x] = 2
end

h = {x: 1}
change(h)
h[:x] #=> 2
```

Answer (score 3):

Ruby does not work that way. There are no pointers, if that's what you mean and it . Arguments are passed by *value*, but these values are themselves references to objects in memory.

What you call "primitives" (eg. the value `1`) are in fact immutable objects in Ruby so it would not make sense to have pointers to them. Passing a variable containing that object is the way to go.

I'm curious about what you want to achieve though.

Comment: Thanx. I wanted pointers for a primitive types. Then do I have to put the primitive types inside a wrapper class and pass the reference of the wrapper?
Isn't there any built-in wrapper types for primitive types in ruby?
(ex: java Integer for int, Double for double )

Comment: @Lahiru there are no primitive types in Ruby, `1` is an object. Maybe you should provide an example. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @Lahiru - in java `Integer` and `Double` are wrappers, but are not mutable, so they can't help you in whatever you wanted to do...